# I have a problem with pulling specific objects from an array in mongoose with updateOne or update

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
edit: async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    const updateCampground = await Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.campground })
    const imgs = req.files.map(el => ({ url: el.path, filename: el.filename }))
    updateCampground.img.push(...imgs)
    await updateCampground.save()
    if (req.body.deleteImg) {
        for (let filename of req.body.deleteImg) {
            await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(filename)
        }
        await updateCampground.updateOne({ $pull: { img: { filename: { $in: req.body.deleteImg } } } })
    }
    req.flash('success', 'Campground modified successfully')
    res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${id}`)
}
```

The main problem is that line here it dose not work and did not remove the selected images in req.body.deletImg (it's not empty) from img[]

```
await updateCampground.updateOne({ $pull: { img: { filename: { $in: req.body.deleteImg } } } })
```

This is img[]

```
    [
  {
    url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dzz5whhe2/image/upload/v1661986678/YelpCamp/jca4is4gpvxrbckmjaxw.jpg',
    filename: 'YelpCamp/jca4is4gpvxrbckmjaxw',
    _id: new ObjectId("630fe78120e2a31b40febe85")
  },
  {
    url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dzz5whhe2/image/upload/v1661986687/YelpCamp/ds9mxvcuafnw3prqg6zp.jpg',
    filename: 'YelpCamp/ds9mxvcuafnw3prqg6zp',
    _id: new ObjectId("630fe78120e2a31b40febe86")
  },
  {
    url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dzz5whhe2/image/upload/v1661995665/YelpCamp/t9qkz1mbg5rastf0ngyn.jpg',
    filename: 'YelpCamp/t9qkz1mbg5rastf0ngyn',
    _id: new ObjectId("63100a9465bffd5fa369ac28")
  },
  {
    url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dzz5whhe2/image/upload/v1661995666/YelpCamp/an95ip1k3etpeikisqzi.jpg',
    filename: 'YelpCamp/an95ip1k3etpeikisqzi',
    _id: new ObjectId("63100a9465bffd5fa369ac29")
  }
]
```

and this is req.body.deleteImg

```
    [
  'YelpCamp/t9qkz1mbg5rastf0ngyn ',
  'YelpCamp/an95ip1k3etpeikisqzi '
]
```

note : the images deleted from cloudinary library but their links still work and they existe somewhere because the URLs in MongoDB is still functional . can someone explain please

Comment: ok thank you i figured it out ...it's the space in req.body.deleteImg strings I just used trim() bruh